# nth-of-type, except for header

Tags: html, css

I've got the following code for altering the cell colors in my table. I would like to keep this behavior, but exclude the header row, which is currently orange because of the nth-of-type odd command.

````
tr:nth-of-type(even) { 
            background: green; 
            color: white; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            width: 70%; 
        } 
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
            background: orange; 
            color: white; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            width: 70%; 
        } ```
````

Comment: If you control the HTML (I assume you do), use `<thead>` for the header rows and `<tbody>` for the table body. No magic necessary.

Comment: @Tomalak Ah okay, simple solution. Excuse my lack of html knowledge. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to skip the first child ( header )

There are other solutions too

```css
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd):not(:first-child) {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>header</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, I had read about a solution similar to this but had my syntax off. Thanks a lot

Comment: @skepticalforever glad i could help. please rate and accept my answer . Thank you ! :D